# How to clone my cloud server locally?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud

I'm working on an IoT project and have my backend running on cloud.

Now, there are a few sites where the connection of the device is not being allowed to the cloud by the authorities but instead they want my cloud infrastructure to be cloned locally.

What's a good strategy to go about it?
Could something like docker come good here?

I'm a beginner at coding and any help would be highly appreciated.
TIA

Edit 1: on my cloud vm I have mqtt broker running along with python application for business logic and mysql database.
When I clone this locally, the cloud setup has to be universal but the local setup is for just the devices within that local network. The local devices have to work with this local setup and independent of the cloud
My concern is whats a quick way to set this up locally without going to the site and installing dependency one by one.

Comment: Welcome on the SF! It seems, your question is too broad for this community. If your VM is a Linux, you might get more help on https://unix.stackexchange.com . Until that, I think your question is essentially: "How to clone a Linux server from which I have only remote access?". And the answer it: there are no wonders, you need to copy everything. How exactly do you copy everything, it already your problem. What I would do, is the following steps: 1. do a full copy of the live system with a a block-level tool or with an rsync. It will result a slightly damaged, but nearly perfect clone.

Comment: The clone will essentially what you will get from a system after a dirty reboot. 2. After that, synchronize everything which is sensitive against hard restarts, it means mainly databases and binary db files. For that, you have your own tools, for example pg_dump / pg_restore in postgresql. 3. re-install the boot mechanism of the clone. | Now the problem if that all of these steps are highly dependent on your currently used softwares and technologies, this is why was your question closed as "too broad". However, instead a step-by-step guide, you should get a higher level answer, here it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is such a broad question that it can't be reasonably answered without *a lot more* information.

Couple of ideas though:

- if it's IoT you're probably using MQTT - you can have a local MQTT broker at each site and forward the messages to your cloud infrastructure from one central secured point.
- if you don't need any cloud-specific features and simply need a way to host your application onsite I'm sure every company of medium or bigger size will have some sort of VMware, OVM or private cloud solution.

But really, without knowing your architecture it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added some more details. Hope that should provide some clarity.